# @font-face not working in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, font-face

I´ve finally continued work on a hobby-project of mine, after months. I had some computer problems at the beginning of the year, had to do a new Windows install, lost the DB, but could retrieve the scripts. As far as I know, everything is exactly the same as before, except for the absolute urls. I´m working purely on localhost. I´m sure everything was working fine in all major browsers before I stopped working on it, unless my memory fails me. Trying to get it to work, I simplified the code / filename:

```
@font-face
{
  font-family: "cabin" ;
  src: url("http://localhost/hrhr/fonts/cabin.ttf");
}

*
{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  font-family: "cabin";
}
```

Some remarks:

- As said, it does not work in Chrome (33), nor does it work in Opera (20).
- It does work in Internet Explorer (11). It already worked without simplifying the code and file name.
- As said, I´m pretty sure everything was working fine a few months ago, and nothing has changed apart from absolute urls, and the browser versions.
- As suggested by an anwser from a similar question, I´ve tried adding the format, this didn´t help.
- I´ve tried variations on quotes.
- It generally doesn´t show up in Chrome developer tools under resources. Strangely sometimes it does (after trying variations on the code), and when that happens, it displays the name right, but the example font is wrong (presumably Times New Roman).
- I´ve tried copying the font file in other folders and using relative urls.
- It displays fine if I remove the @font-face rule, install the font, and just use the local reference, and it also works if I use a Google webfont reference.

I think I´m grossly overlooking something, but Googling didn´t help me yet, and I find it strange IE has no problems whatsoever with my code. Thanks in advance.

Edit:
The font can be found here:
http://www.impallari.com/cabin

Edit 2:
Thanks to Dima´s anwser, I´ve solved the problem, but I´m no closer to understanding it.

I used the fonts and script the site provided me, like I said, that worked, then step by step, I removed elements so it resembled the original situation more and more, until it stopped working again. So basically, I can get it to work with my script and the "converted" ttf file, so the problem seems to be inherent to the original ttf file itself. The script, file paths or cross browser compatibility aren´t the problem. Once converted, Chrome had no issues with it. But I have no idea what the technical difference is.

Tomorrow I´ll see if I can find a font viewer to see if I can find the difference. I also may mail the creator of the font (asking if he´s aware of problems with it), and I´d like to know if other people have issues with the font "as is", so without converting it. Unless someone gives me a technical explanation, I´ll accept Dima´s anwser and will just learn to "convert" the font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using it like this:

```
 @font-face {
  font-family: 'Cabin';
  src: url("/fonts/cabin.eot");
  src: url("/fonts/cabin.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("/portals/0/fonts/cabin.woff") format("woff"), url("/fonts/cabin.ttf") format("truetype"), url("/fonts/cabin.svg#cabin") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal; 
}
```

this will make sure that all browsers are covered... your best bet is to upload `.ttf` font to  web font generator like [this one](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) or [this one](http://www.font2web.com/), it will then generate the web font in different formats and you'll be able to download it... it will also include the CSS for it which will be similar to the one I showed above

**EDIT**: to answer your question about why that is, there is no right or wrong answer, that's just the way it is. Different browsers support different font formats. You can read about some of it [here](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/how-to-achieve-cross-browser-font-face-support/)

Comment: I checked your link, it says the font is corrupt. I´ve re-downloaded the font from its source (which I will add in the original post), but it still says its  corrupt. But, when I install the font (the exact same file), and use a local reference (so without the @font-face rule), the font works fine in Chrome, so I doubt any corruption is the cause of this problem?

Comment: yeah sometimes it happens.. just use another web font generator tool for it... there are plenty, this one is just the most popular

Comment: I used http://everythingfonts.com/font-face which worked for me. It solved the problem, however I´m not much closer to understanding it. I´ll update the original post.

Comment: No, like I added in my edit: it has nothing to do with browser compatibility. ttf is one of the most widely supported font formats, and the font works fine when converted. It also used to work a few months ago, like I said, the same font used to work in all major browsers a few months ago, using the same code. So I want to know what the conversion does to the ttf file, and I´d like to know what happened in those few months that changed the behaviour. Are the font specifications updated? Are the CSS specifications updated? Are the new browser versions interpreting things differently?

Comment: No. I'l mess about with some other fonts, in the meantime, I've accepted your awswer.

Answer (score 0):

You can even use `@import url('fonts/cabin.ttf');`

And to use it, open your TTF File, and see the name of the font, if it says Cabin, then, `font-family: 'Cabin';`